# Ionic 4:Error using ion-bottom-drawer component

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am attempting to use the `ion-bottom-drawer` component in my app but i keep running into errors. The component does not seem to be recognized

Steps to reproduce :

create ionic4 project

> npm i ion-bottom-drawer --save
>      npm i hammerjs@2.0.8 --save
>      npm i @types/hammerjs@2.0.36 --save

import IonBottomDrawerModule in **app.module.ts**
add component to homepage

```js
<ion-bottom-drawer 
    [(state)]="drawerState" 
    [minimumHeight]="minimumHeight" 
    [dockedHeight]="dockedHeight" 
    [shouldBounce]="shouldBounce"
    [distanceTop]="distanceTop"
>
    <div class="drawer-content">
        Bottom Drawer Content
    </div>
</ion-bottom-drawer>
```

The component is not recognized despite following all steps in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You should use the appropriate values.

Please use as below.

```
<ion-bottom-drawer [minimumHeight]=50 [dockedHeight]=350
  [shouldBounce]=true [distanceTop]=50>
  <div class="drawer-content">
    Bottom Drawer Content
  </div>
</ion-bottom-drawer>
```

Here is an example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bottom-drawer?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

Answer (score 0):

Look in your `homepage.module.ts` and import it in there as well:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '',
        component: HomePage
      }
    ]),
    IonBottomDrawerModule
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

I'm still learning myself, but I think this is because of the lazy loading feature. Every page gets its own module.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I had to create a component module and import IonBottomDrawerModule there then include CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA as a schema in the module and just use the component the way the documentation states.

Comment: yes right I am also using same and imported IonBottomDrawerModule and included in component module.